# How can I write this using forEach How can I write the code from bellow using a forEach instead of for

Tags: javascript

```
for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i += 1) {  
   if (numbers[i] % 2 === 0)
 {       
numbers[i] = numbers[i] + value;    
 }
```

Comment: numbers.forEach( (elem) => {                  // перебираем 1 параметр
    if (numbers[elem] % 2 === 0) {                     // ищем четные елементы
                                                                         // к четным добавляем значение велью
     
     numbers[elem] = numbers[elem] + value; 
     
    }
     
    
  })  пытался делать так

Comment: `numbers.forEach( (num, index, array) => {if (num%2 === 0) array[index] += value} );`

Comment: а так , что бы numbers не изменять , а ка бы записывалось в некоторую копию?

Comment: `let numbers_copy = numbers.map(num => num%2 ? num : num + value);`

Comment: Не правильно выразился то , что мы получаем через forEach реально запихнуть ка бы в новый массив, что бы параметр numbers , был не изменный

Comment: `map` не модифицирует массив `numbers` и возвращает новый массив.

Comment: Переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык в соответствии с сообществом.

Comment: Я начинающий , сейчас попробую прочитать твой код , "создаем переменную копию параметра numbers  , дальше на параметр numbers применяем метод map который  вызывает коллбек-функцию для каждого элемента исходного массива, а результат её работы записывает в новый массив, который и будет результатом выполнения метода, потом внутри метода проверяем на четность если num true плюсуем value если false оставляем без изменений.    " Верно?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Раз, ты уже разобрался, вот тебе еще пару решений

```js
const changeEven = (numbers, value)=>{
    const arr = [];

    numbers.forEach((num)=>{
        if(num % 2 === 0)num += value;
        arr.push(num);
    });

    return arr;
};

const a = changeEven([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 10);
console.log(1, a);

//

const changeEven2 = (numbers, value)=>{
    return numbers.map((num)=>{
        if(num % 2 === 0)num += value;
        return num;
    });
};

const b = changeEven2([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 10);
console.log(2, b);

//

const changeEven3 = (numbers, value)=>numbers.map((num)=>(num % 2 === 0 ? num + value : num));
const c = changeEven3([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 10);
console.log(3, c);
```

Comment: Крутяк!!!! больше всего через map  понравилось делать.

Comment: Даже не знал , что в возврат можно ставить возврат

Comment: но мой вариант самый простой и понятный для  начинающих динозавров js

Answer (score 0):

```
function changeEven(numbers, value) {
  
  const numb = [];

  numbers.forEach((num) => { // перебираем елементы
    if (num%2 === 0)  // проверяем на четность 
    num += value;  // если четное плюсуем велью
    numb.push(num); // пушим в новый массив
    console.log (numb);
    
  });
      return numb ; // возвращаем новый массив
   
  
}
changeEven([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 10);
```

Comment: решил через forEach всем спасибо толкнули на нужную мысль